# How to integrate HTML markup from another URL in C#

Tags: c#, html, integration

I have an aspx file that loads HTML markup. This markup contains a div element which is basically a container for another HTML markup retrieved from another URL. A code snippet would look like this:

```
<div id="container">
<%= RetrieveIntegrationMarkup() %>
</div>
```

What is the best way to retrieve the markup in the RetrieveIntegrationMarkup()? Currently, we are using a workaround to accept self-signed SSL certificates, but it only works in our test environments. It doesn't work in the production environment.

I don't know if this will help, but here's the snippet of the said method:

```
HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Revalidate);
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();

Uri serviceUri = new Uri(integrationUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(serviceUri);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    markup= sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "it doesn't work" is quite broad. Can you give the exact error message?

Comment: That's one information that I'm still trying to find. Our production environment's custom error settings do not show the details. I'll add it here once I find out

Comment: Well, without knowing what goes wrong, it is sort of hard to help you. I would guess (*guess!*) that it is related to your self-signed SSL certificate, though.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The actual reason I asked here is because it's going to take some time before we can deploy a patch to the production environment, that will allow me to see the details.

Self-signed certificate is also my primary suspect.